# How to amplify or exaggerate a small change in value of a variable as compared to previous value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that is very slightly changing its value on the y-axis. I want to amplify this change so that its is more noticeable.

My idea is to simply compare the current vale and previous value, find the difference and then add that difference to the y axis value along with an amplification factor. So this is what I came up with:

```
public float amplifyBy = 1.5f;
void Update()
    {
        // This calculates the center position of 4 objects and sets the transform of this object to this position
        optimalCentre = (targetAnchor1.position + targetAnchor2.position + targetAnchor3.position + targetAnchor4.position) / 4;

        // below is to amplify the y movement as there is almost no visible bounciness.
        if (optimalCentre.y != previousY)
        {
            // find difference in change
            float diff_ = previousY - optimalCentre.y;
            transform.position = new Vector3(optimalCentre.x, optimalCentre.y + (diff_ * amplifyBy), optimalCentre.z);
            Debug.Log(diff_);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = optimalCentre;
        }


        previousY = transform.position.y;
    }
```

This is not working as expected, As what appears to be happening is that any amplification factor applied is incremented up until infinity and the gameObject very quickly goes beyond bounds.

Thank you

Comment: First of all you shouldn't compare two floats with `==` or `!=`, two floats will practically **never** be equal. More about it [here](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). So it means that `optimalCentre.y != previousY` might always be true and your transform so might change every frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a tolerance value like

```
const float Tolerance = 0.1f;
```

then compare it like

```
if(Math.Abs(optimalCentre.y - previousY) < Tolerance)
    {
        // find difference in change
        float diff_ = previousY - optimalCentre.y;
        transform.position = new Vector3(optimalCentre.x, optimalCentre.y + (diff_ * amplifyBy), optimalCentre.z);
        Debug.Log(diff_);
    }
```